# (Set) Comprehension from multiple values

Tags: python, set-comprehension

Suppose I’ve got a list `l = [1,2,3]` and I want to create a set of all numbers in that list and their squares. Ideally, in a single comprehension expression.

Best I can come up with is (two iterations over the list):

```
set(_ for _ in l).union(_ * _ for _ in l)
```

Comment: It is clearer than a nested generator comprehension as I think. BTW, it can be simplified to `{_ for _ in l} | {_ ** 2 for _ in l}`

Comment: @Sraw That’s synonymous with the explicit `union()` function and still requires two iterations over the list.

Comment: I know, Um.. It is difficult to explain. There was an answer that gave a nested generator comprehension and I though that looked confusing although it was really shorter. But now that answer has been deleted! Surely what I write is a synonym, I just want to say it can be shorter and even clearer.

Comment: Actually I find a solution: `{*(l + [_ ** 2 for _ in l])}`.

Comment: @Sraw Still iterates twice over `l` ;-) Take a look at the answer below.

Comment: That answer is the same as the deleted answer.

Comment: As an aside, `_` is conventionally used for *throwaway* variables, e.g. `[1 for _ in range(5)]`, it will be confusing to other Python programmers if you use something like `[_ for _ in l]`. Furthermore, `set(x for x in l)` => `set(l)`.

Comment: Actually, as I has tested, `set(l + [i ** 2 for i in l])` is faster than `{y for x in l for y in (x, x**2)}
`. Using `timeit` with 1000000 iterations.

Comment: @Sraw Interesting, could you please make your observation an additional answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own code can be shortened to:

```
set(l).union(x**2 for x in l)
```

in which I renamed `_` to `x`, because `_` indicates the value is not important, but it is.

Strictly speaking you're still iterating over the `list` twice, but the first time implicitly.

If you insist to iterate once, you'd get this:

```
{y for x in l for y in (x, x**2)}
```

which is a double comprehension that encompasses the following:

```
result = set()
for x in l:
    for y in (x, x**2):
        result.add(y)
```

Comment: That’s that funky double-nested comprehension that I was trying for 

Comment: @Jens The order of the `for`s is always a gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, `set(l + [i ** 2 for i in l])` is a better solution. It is clearer than a nested generator comprehension.

And I have done a benchmark:

```
import timeit
l = list(range(5))
print(timeit.timeit("set(l + [_ ** 2 for _ in l])", 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals())))
print(timeit.timeit("{y for x in l for y in (x, x**2)}", 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals())))
```

output:

```
3.0309128219996637
3.1958301850008866
```

It shows `set(l + [i ** 2 for i in l])` is a little faster. The reason I think is that nested generator comprehension need to create internal object `(x, x**2)` for every loop, that makes it slow.

## Update

```
import timeit
l = list(range(200000))
print(timeit.timeit("set(l + [_ ** 2 for _ in l])", 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()), number=100))
print(timeit.timeit("{y for x in l for y in (x, x**2)}", 'from __main__ import ' + ', '.join(globals()), number=100))
```

output:

```
16.46792753900081
19.72252997099895
```

Comment: For a list this small, the results are meaningless. When it grows large, the fact that you're constructing the whole list first _could_ become a factor. More interesting would be a benchmark with a list of 100000+ elements.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Updated.